# Python P andas compare two excel files and export

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to compare to excel file and output to a new excel file for import to our stupid ERP, to improve my workload but I have some question

my excel file  like this, around 17 columns   `NAME DESCRIPTION Our REF TEAM ADDRESS LINE1  ... ........` only  ADDRESS LINE1 ADDRESS LINE2 and tel need to compare' because the ADDRESS and tel will change by 3rd party

The excel has 2 worksheets named cust code and vendor code,  how to compare  two excel with  2 worksheets

```
         #compare
lastdaySet = pd.read_excel('lastday.xlsx',sheet_name =0,index=False,inplace=True)
todaySet = pd.read_excel('today.xlsx', sheet_name =0,index=False, inplace=True)    
difference = todaySet[todaySet!=lastdaySet]
 print (difference)
#Output excel
        ....
```

but has  error
Output error

```
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "C:/Users/SupportTeamA/PycharmProjects/untitled2/excelhandel.py", line 74,
> in <module>
>     difference = todaySet[todaySet != lastdaySet]   File "C:\Users\SupportTeamA\PycharmProjects\untitled2\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops\__init__.py",
> line 838, in f
>     raise ValueError( ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled DataFrame objects
```

Comment: What is label you want compare with lastdayset..you need to give label of two xls..you can't do todayset[todayset-somelabel]..because todayset is object reference of xls

Comment: @NAGARAJS I found it only compare the old value if the new  value will have an error

Comment: maybe try to define a differences variable like `diff = numpy.where(LastdaySet == TodaySet, True, False)` and then dump this `diff` into an excel sheet ?

Answer (score 2):

It does not compare if the number of rows in the two sheets is different and gives same error.  Here is a workaround when todaySet contains greater number of rows than lastdaySet:

```
import pandas as pd

lastdaySet = pd.read_excel('lastday.xlsx',sheet_name =0,index=False,inplace=True)
todaySet = pd.read_excel('today.xlsx', sheet_name =0,index=False, inplace=True)

lenToday = len (todaySet.index)
lenLastday = len(lastdaySet.index)
if lenToday > lenLastday:
    temp = todaySet.iloc[:lenLastday]
    difference = temp[temp!=lastdaySet]

    remaining = todaySet.iloc[lenLastday:]
    difference = pd.concat([difference, remaining])  #.drop_duplicates().reset_index(drop=True)
    difference = difference.reset_index(drop=True)
else:
    difference = todaySet[todaySet!=lastdaySet]
print ('Final Diff:')
print (difference)
```

For comparison of Sheet2, you'll set `sheet_name = 1`.

Comment: Thank, I have more question, How I display the full row, now the Output `NaN,NewValue,NaN,` how to change to `OldValue,NewValue,OldValue`

Comment: @petercheung Try this plz: `print (difference.fillna(todaySet))`

Comment: Thank now i use , `dropnone = difference.dropna(how='all')
filldata = (dropnone.fillna(todaySet))
print(filldata)`

Comment: @petercheung Not the answer you wanted?

Comment: instead of rows how to get specific column where the difference occurs while comparing two excel sheets . this would be helpful for me

Answer (score 0):

the error because you read all of sheets you need only specific column can you use the following code i hope to help you

```
import pandas as pd
`import os
  #compare
lastdaySet = pd.read_excel('lastday.xlsx',sheet_name =0,usecols =['column_name1','column_name2'])
todaySet = pd.read_excel('today.xlsx', sheet_name =0,usecols =['column_name1','column_name2'])    
difference = todaySet[todaySet!=lastdaySet]
 print (difference)
#Output excel
difference.to_excel("output.xlsx")
os.startfile('"output.xlsx"')
```

Comment: Welcome. Don't sweat it, they're gone. This was a poorly formulated question since there is no [mre]. OP should have provided sample of sheets after reading to pandas